# How can I print "@" * 15 in java?

Tags: java

How can I print this in java?
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
I know in python it is like this:
`print("@" * 15)`

Comment: You don't use multiplication for strings. Use a loop?

Comment: Try this.  System.out.println("@".repeat(15));